# Spinning only half an object / twisting an object

Tags: animation

does anybody know how something like this can be achieved?

https://www.pinterest.de/pin/760334349575174444/?nic=1a

Comment: Hello! Please display here a picture of what you want

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! As @moonboots said, please post a picture or a description of what you want. That way the question will still be understandable even if the Pinterest link is down. Also, please state what you have already tried as it shows that you have made at least a little effort yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example file:

[image]

1. Add a plane and subdivide it multiple times.
2. Add bones to both ends and parent the armature with empty groups to the plane.
3. Select the half of the verts and assign it to the correct bone's vertex group, then repeat it with the remaining verts an the other bone's vertex group.
4. Go to weight paint mode, turn on vertex selection, select all the verts by pressing "a" then choose smooth from the weights menu.
5. In the pop-up menu select all groups for subset, increase the factor to 1 and increase the iterations till the rainbow reaching through the plane.
6. Animate the armature.

[image]